# Maven: no Scala classes bundles in jar

Tags: java, scala, maven

My project structure looks like

```
project/pom.xml
       /services/pom.xml
                src/main/scala/(scala class here)
                src/main/resources/application.conf
       /manager/pom.xml
                src/main/scala/(scala class here)
                src/main/resources/manager.conf
```

The `services/pom.xml` looks like

```
   <properties>
        <akka-http.version>1.0</akka-http.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.shn.enterpriseconnector</groupId>
            <artifactId>manager</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-experimental_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka-http.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-spray-json-experimental_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka-http.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

but when I do `mvn clean install`, and check the contents of jar, I see

```
$ jar -tvf service/target/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
     0 Thu Jul 30 09:45:12 PDT 2015 META-INF/
   130 Thu Jul 30 09:45:10 PDT 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   629 Thu Jul 30 09:45:12 PDT 2015 application.conf
     0 Thu Jul 30 09:45:12 PDT 2015 META-INF/maven/
     0 Thu Jul 30 09:45:12 PDT 2015 META-INF/maven/com.shn.enterpriseconnector/
     0 Thu Jul 30 09:45:12 PDT 2015 META-INF/maven/com.shn.enterpriseconnector/service/
  1284 Thu Jul 30 09:38:30 PDT 2015 META-INF/maven/com.shn.enterpriseconnector/service/pom.xml
   126 Thu Jul 30 09:45:12 PDT 2015 META-INF/maven/com.shn.enterpriseconnector/service/pom.properties
```

In `project.pom.xml`, I have

```
<properties>
    <scala-library.version>2.11.7</scala-library.version>
    <akka.version>2.3.12</akka.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala-library.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But I do not see anything, none of my project classes, no dependency classes

Visually, the structure looks like
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: are the classes actually being compiled during install?

Answer (score 3):

At a minimum, this should work:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had spent time reading and trying couple of things and following `project/pom.xml` changes work well for me

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>EnterpriseConnectorServer</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```